# Remove all data matching ID if first row meets specific condition

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to remove all data for `client_id` when the `score` for the **first** item for that client (when sorted by date) matches  a specific condition. From my reading, it would appear that `data.table` can do it, and I have been able to *nearly* get there.

Here's some sample data:

```
client_id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4)
date <- c("1/1/2021", "1/2/2021", "1/3/2021", "5/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "11/1/2021", "1/2/2021", "10/9/2021", "15/9/2021", "16/10/2021")
date <- as.Date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')
score <- c(15,10,19,20,10,25,20,15,10,30,5)
df <- data.frame(client_id, date, score)
```

And I tried this:

```
df <-setDT(df)
df[client_id %in% df[score > 16, client_id], ]
```

I was hoping that this would remove client_id 1 because the **first** score is < 16. However, this seems to only remove them all when all scores are > 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably using `which.min(date)` is safer:

```r
df[,.SD[score[which.min(date)]>16],by=client_id]
```

Comment: Thought I'd also share this here as a solution for anyone who is trying to do something similar. This is where I was trying to do the same thing with dates. If the first date for a client_id was less than the date specified then remove all the associated data for those client_ids:

df[!client_id %in% df[, .(first_date = min(date)), by = client_id][first_date < as.Date("2021-09-01"), client_id]]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.SD` with `first`, provided that dates in `df` are in ascending order:

```
df[,.SD[first(score)>16],by=client_id]
   client_id       date score
       <num>     <Date> <num>
1:         2 2021-01-05    20
2:         2 2021-01-10    10
3:         3 2021-01-10    25
4:         3 2021-01-11    20
5:         3 2021-02-01    15
6:         3 2021-09-10    10
7:         4 2021-09-15    30
8:         4 2021-10-16     5
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` option:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  arrange(client_id, date) %>% 
  group_by(client_id) %>% 
  filter(first(score) > 16)
```

**Output**

```
  client_id date       score
      <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1         2 2021-01-05    20
2         2 2021-01-10    10
3         3 2021-01-10    25
4         3 2021-01-11    20
5         3 2021-02-01    15
6         3 2021-09-10    10
7         4 2021-09-15    30
8         4 2021-10-16     5
```

Or another `data.table` option:

```
df[df[, .I[first(score)>16], by=client_id]$V1]

   client_id       date score
1:         2 2021-01-05    20
2:         2 2021-01-10    10
3:         3 2021-01-10    25
4:         3 2021-01-11    20
5:         3 2021-02-01    15
6:         3 2021-09-10    10
7:         4 2021-09-15    30
8:         4 2021-10-16     5
```